# Using Internal Link with Angular 9

Tags: html, angular

EDIT: I using href and section with id, to scroll to the div with the id specified, in the same component.

I did with a simple href="contato" and a section with id="contato" and works, but...
i want to know how to do this without the error **"Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'contato' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'contato'"** on the console!

```
  <span class="nav-list" id="nav-list">
        <div fxFlex fxShow="true" fxHide.sm="true"></div>
            <a href="#inicio" class="nav-list-menu" alt="home">
                Home
            </a>
            <a href="#recursos" class="nav-list-menu" alt="Recursos">
                Recursos
            </a>
            <a href="#contato" class="nav-list-menu" alt="Contato">
                Contato
            </a>
            <a (click)="this.login()" class="nav-list-menu enter-button"  alt="Entrar no sistema">
                Entrar
            </a>
    </span>


<section id="recursos" style="width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: white;"></section>
```

Comment: put your html code also

Comment: Just show the code of your routes path and the html code where you have used that particular route

Comment: Question edited. All i want is just to scroll to a in div ( in the same component ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do like this

**document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView();**

**Note don't use # as prefix while providing Id**

An example would be like

```
element.scrollIntoView();
element.scrollIntoView(alignToTop); // Boolean parameter
element.scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions); // Object parameter


var element = document.getElementById("box");

element.scrollIntoView();
element.scrollIntoView(false);
element.scrollIntoView({block: "end"});
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
```

you can access the component in angular by this way

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <div #myDiv>Some text</div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

There is a brief Documentation in Mozilla

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Just check it if your works get done Just Upvote and Approve if it works..!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define routes like this in appRoutingModule.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first-component', component: FirstComponent 
},
  { path: 'second-component', component: b 
  SecondComponent },
];
```

Now the html code will be like

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/first-component" 
routerLinkActive="active">First Component</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/second-component" 
routerLinkActive="active">Second Component</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope you get your answer just approve it if it works and upvote too ;)

Comment: I think he also wants a hash fragment in the url, to scroll to the div with the id specified.

Comment: Hmm let once the question be clear than we can edit the answer..

Comment: Yes, Pieterjan it's right, question edited, with code. 
I trying to scroll to a div ( in the same component ). It's working but give me this error message on console;

Comment: ok ,let me figure out something..!!